# Android Date: finding future date

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am looking and have been looking for a good example or tutorial on calculating/finding a future date by adding a set number of days.

I have a date picker that opens when user clicks on EditText so they can select the date, then I'm wanting to add lets say 56 days to that date. then show a Toast or Dialog that displays the future date from the date set. Then after i learn and figure that out I'm going to have my app show a notification on that date.

not sure if i should be using calendar or alarm,, oh and this data is being stored in a SQLite DB. like always hope i have given enough info to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

any help, pointers or suggestions will be awesome, as i am still learning both java and android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void getFutureDate(Date currentDate, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(currentDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);

    Date futureDate = cal.getTime();
}
```

**currentDate**: Date from date picker, 
**days**: Number of days to be added to currentDate

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 3):

Why not Calendar.add(field, amount)?

From that, yes, you could use AlarmManager. I don't know much, but I believe that would do.

Of course, your question is generic and does not add an specific problem. That said, considering the pattern, I believe the above will do.

Comment: And the rest is up to you! Research the implementation details. :-)

Comment: doesn't that just add to the one specific field?

Comment: i'll give that a try, thanks for a push in a direction to try out

Comment: You're so welcome. If you need any clarification, just comment here and I'll know. Good luck!

Comment: I stand corrected - was sure I'd tested it in my TV Guide app. Perhaps just the month rollover and not the year. Doh!

Comment: *"doesn't that just add to the one specific field?"* As I had said in the other answer, no, `add` takes care of changing larger fields as needed, which is the optimal solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code to get future date and time. Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DYavHADmB8/

```
    mDateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.future_date_time);
    mGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_date_time);

    mGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
            Date future = c.getTime();

            mDateTime.setText("Future: " + future);
        }
    });
```